# Errors while starting JBoss Server

Tags: jboss, jboss-4.2.x

I am trying to start JBoss server from eclipse but I am getting some exceptions as below. Later I also tried from command prompt but still getting same exceptions

```
01:35:49,227 ERROR [STDERR] java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Servers\jboss-4.2.3\server\default\data\tx-object-store\HashedActionStore\defaultStore\Recovery\TransactionStatusManager\#161#\-3f5796f4_caed_4fc48ed7_0 (Access is denied)
01:35:49,227 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
01:35:49,227 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
01:35:49,227 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
01:35:49,227 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.objectstore.ShadowingStore.write_state(ShadowingStore.java:749)
01:35:49,227 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.objectstore.FileSystemStore.write_committed(FileSystemStore.java:209)
01:35:49,227 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.objectstore.ObjectStore.write_committed(ObjectStore.java:281)
01:35:49,227 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.TransactionStatusManagerItem.saveThis(TransactionStatusManagerItem.java:300)
01:35:49,227 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.TransactionStatusManagerItem.markAsDead(TransactionStatusManagerItem.java:117)
01:35:49,227 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.TransactionStatusConnector.setDeadTSM(TransactionStatusConnector.java:193)
01:35:49,227 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.TransactionStatusConnector.test(TransactionStatusConnector.java:83)
01:35:49,227 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.ExpiredTransactionStatusManagerScanner.scan(ExpiredTransactionStatusManagerScanner.java:147)
01:35:49,227 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.ExpiredEntryMonitor.run(ExpiredEntryMonitor.java:212)
```

and also

```
java.sql.SQLException: The database is already in use by another process: org.hsqldb.persist.NIOLockFile@f3788b66[file =C:\Servers\jboss-4.2.3\server\default\data\hypersonic\localDB.lck, exists=true, locked=false, valid=false, fl =null]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Servers\jboss-4.2.3\server\default\data\hypersonic\localDB.lck (Access is denied)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.jdbc.HypersonicDatabase.getConnection(HypersonicDatabase.java:768)
    at org.jboss.jdbc.HypersonicDatabase.startStandaloneDatabase(HypersonicDatabase.java:618)
    at org.jboss.jdbc.HypersonicDatabase.startService(HypersonicDatabase.java:564)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:304)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy42.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.XSLSubDeployer.start(XSLSubDeployer.java:197)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:304)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have also set the environmental variables JAVA_HOME and JBOSS_HOME
I am using Postgresql as database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those "Access is denied" errors are probably caused by insufficient ntfs permissions.
It seems that this JBoss instance was run under different user before recent tries.
That launch created some files only accessible to the first user but not to the second.

Possible solutions:

- manually delete problem files
- [fix ntfs permissions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810881/en-us?fr=1)
- [run jboss with admin privileges](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff431742.aspx)

Comment: Did you try to just delete `C:\Servers\jboss-4.2.3\server\default\data\hypersonic\localDB.lck`?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the following steps

1. close JBOSS and eclipse there after
2. delete files from jboss-6.0.0.Final\server\default\data\hypersonic; localDB.backup, localDB.data, localDB.lck, localDB.log,localDB.properties and localDB.script
3. start eclipse and then JBoss server.

Worked well for me

Thanks